# Magento 2.4 Admin invalid parent id Dotdigitalgroup_Email::marketing_automation

Tags: magento, magento2

I cannot login to Magento 2.4 Admin after upgrade. It's saying invalid parent id Dotdigitalgroup_Email::marketing_automation.

I also created a new user-id and password using below syntax

> php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user='new-admin'
> --admin-password='!admin123!' --admin-email='info@domain.com' --admin-firstname='Jon' --admin-lastname='Doe'

Login not working please help.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (OutOfRangeException): Specified invalid parent id (Dotdigitalgroup_Email::marketing_automation)

Exception #0 (OutOfRangeException): Specified invalid parent id (Dotdigitalgroup_Email::marketing_automation)
<pre>#1 Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Config->_initMenu() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Menu/Config.php:111]
#2 Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Config->getMenu() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Url.php:365]
#3 Magento\Backend\Model\Url->_getMenu() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Url.php:325]
#4 Magento\Backend\Model\Url->getStartupPageUrl() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:187]
#5 Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->_processUrlKeys() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Request/BackendValidator.php:175]
#6 Magento\Backend\App\Request\BackendValidator->validate() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/CompositeValidator.php:40]
#7 Magento\Framework\App\Request\CompositeValidator->validate() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:160]
#8 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:118]
#9 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#10 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#11 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#12 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#13 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#14 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:263]
#15 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [index.php:45]
</pre>
<pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have Dotdigitalgroup_Email and Dotdigitalgroup_Chat modules disabled, please disable Dotdigitalgroup_Sms module too (added in Magento 2.4.x)

bin/magento module:disable Dotdigitalgroup_Sms --clear-static-content

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this error is similar. Try to find solutions according to topic below. Maybe it can solve your problem.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229205/magento-2-admin-page-specified-invalid-parent-id-weltpixel-backendweltpixel

Answer (score 0):

Here it may be possible that you have disabled Dotdigitalgroup_Email module for some reason.

So for that please check here in config file you can see the below result for Dotdigitalgroup_Email this module.

'Dotdigitalgroup_Email' => 0,

Enable this Analytics module using the below command or change from 0 to 1 in config.php file.

php bin/magento module:enable Dotdigitalgroup_Email

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush